# Collaborative coding - .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, collaboration

I have a group of people who work on a project from their homes.

Can anyone suggest me ways in which we can have a single repository of the code on the server and all the guys editing that code and testing/debugging it on their local machines?

We are using .NET platform and using Visual Studio 2010 as the IDE. I was rather keen on knowing if there could be a single repository for the code and local editing of it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate over at Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/940/what-are-your-favorite-version-control-systems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to research [Source Control](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Visual+Studio+2010+Source+Control)

[Here's what Wikipedia has to say about Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)

[Here's a Visual Guide to Source Control](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/)

Comment: To support your answer. I found this elaborate explanation of installing and getting started here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dndcSJc4uYU

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Git](http://git-scm.com) for source control and getting yourself an on-line account with [GitHub](https://github.com/).

GitHub can act as a central location where your team can pull and push code to and is a lot less hassle than maintaining your own source control server.

We use the excellent GUI tool [Git Extentions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) to make working with Git easy on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).  One of you should host this and it should be accessible to the outside world.  If you're worried about firewalls, I suggest installing [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) (Visual SVN server is free for the non-enterprise edition, and the 10-seat non-commercial Hamachi is free also).

VisualSVN also do a [plug-in](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) for Visual Studio which integrates Tortoise SVN directly.  It's pretty cheap too, and works fantastically.  Note, the plug-in is NOT essential to work with VisualSVN, it just makes life a little easier when working with Visual Studio solutions.  I managed very well without it for quite some time, but when I did buy it, I never looked back.

Comment: VisualSVN is produced by CollabNet, which maintains the basic SVN server and command-line client. There are several other GUI clients available which build on the command-line tool; my personal fave is TortoiseSVN, which is a free WinEx plug-in (provides right-click menu support in shell windows). They also make AnkhSVN, a VS plug-in which isn't quite as good as VisualSVN, but works well and is free. There's a lot of good open-source developer tools out there, and there are some others well worth the cost.

Comment: Yes, the VisualSVN client includes TortoiseSVN (which I was using before using the VS plug-in).  If you're on Windows, it's the way to go, imho.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your looking for a source control solution. [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) are probably your best options.

See [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) for the Git plugin for Visual Studio.
See [VisualHg](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) for the Mercurial plugin for Visual Studio (requires [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things I can advise you.

At first, as mentioned, you should use a Source Control. 
It might be [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVN)
or [GIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)
or [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) (it's not free and very expensive!)
or [SourceSafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceSafe)

At second, you guys need some tracking tool, such as JIRA or TFS. It will allow you to track all issues you assign to coworkers.

At third, you need some kind of continious integration stuff, such as [TeamCity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) or [CruiseControl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl).

As you can see, there are a lot of problems to resolve. What I can advise you is to use some team-work web-platforms such as [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) that can provide you all things I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For distributed source/version control, you could do worse than [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/index.html). You can use it for free, but you're limited to 2 users and 5 client workspaces. If you're project is open-source, you can apply for a free license.

Anything else you need to pay for. By the standards of configuration management software, its not hideously expensive...something like $750/seat in small quantities.

The nice thing about it is that it's designed to work across wide area networks.